# Blank line when fetching data from firebase in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, blank-line

So I have blank line when fetching data from firebase like this:

[image]

console log in render shows data but can't show it in line.

action:

```
export function fetchInputs() {
return dispatch => {
    firebase_db_fetch.on('value', snapshot => {
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_INPUTS,
            payload: snapshot.val()
        });
    });
};
}
```

trying to render:

```
renderInputs() {
    return _.map(this.props.inputs, input => {
        return 
            <li className="list-group-item" key={this.inputs} >
                {this.inputs}
            </li>
        );
    });
}
```

and in class,

```
<div>
    <h3 className="h3Popis">Popis stavki:</h3>
        <ul className="list-group">
            {this.renderInputs()}
        </ul>
</div>
```

and also have a warning:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `InputsIndex`

So how to render data in line?
Thank you for comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in helper function that renders every row, this.props.input;

want to refer to similar question, asked by my own: [Insert specific Firebase database values to table React Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51752660/insert-specific-firebase-database-values-to-table-react-redux)

I think it is a good help for rendering whole object or specific value of that object!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put another type of value in key? Right now you have array. Try string or number

Comment: Yes and I was successful in my last try, now I don't have error for the key, but the lines stay blank...