# Insert specific Firebase database values to table React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I have firebase database that looks like this:
[firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sQnf.png)

I want to insert specific values from that database (adress, city, owner) into table that looks like this: 
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI8mS.png)

fething data from firebase looks like this:

```
export function FetchData() {
  return dispatch => {
    firebase_db.on('value', snapshot => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_DATA, 
        payload: snapshot.val()
      });
    });
  }
}
```

and I'm fetching it with componentDidMount():

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.FetchData()
}
```

Then when I console.log this.props.data result is:
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik8JX.png)

I'm mapping over list with function renderData():

```
renderData(dataList) {
    return _.map(this.props.data, (post, key) => {
        return <DataRow key={key} post={post} id={key} />
    })
}
```

and that is reason why are there two lines with delete button in the table(don't mind about that button, I will move it to the end later...).

**So how can I get access to specific property(like adress or owner)?**
When I try this.props.data.adress it says just `undefined`, probably because it is rendered before there is some data in the props... Also, when I make single key as a global variable in the console and then try temp1.adress, I get wanted, correct value: "Adress2"

**How to put all those adress value from the database to adress column in the table?**
Maybe to use some middleware(reduxPromise or reduxThunk)?

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say:

> So how can I get access to specific property(like address or owner)?
>   When I try this.props.data.address it says just undefined, probably
>   because it is rendered before there is some data in the props... Also,
>   when I make single key as a global variable in the console and then
>   try temp1.adress, I get wanted, correct value: "Adress2"

based on the log you showed on the image, I am quite sure that is because your `this.props.data` is an object with keys like **-LJNHbYR...XtZr** (a hash basically) so to access the **address** or the **owner** you would have to access it like

```
this.props.data[< hash_value >].address
this.props.data[< hash_value >].owner
```

And since you are using **< DataRow />** inside a **map** loop it would be great if you'd show us how is implemented this component

Comment: And one more thing is that if you are going to work with async calls then [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) could be a good idea

Comment: Firstly, thank your for your answer, my render data now firstly checks is this.props.data is empty  object with the lodash help (if (_.isEmpty(this.props.data))) and map function goes like this: return Object.keys(this.props.data).map((post, key) =>... so I can access specific value with this.props.data[post]... Did not try using redux-thunk, but as you said, could be a good idea... now I have one last problem, how to pass that hash value to delete action? will post another question beacuse it is messy to write it here...